# How do I set a button that can only be pressed with a specific role?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

This is the code:

```
class SimpleView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
         self.start_time = None
         self.stop_time = None
         super().__init__(timeout=None)
        
        



    @discord.ui.button(label="⬆️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="1")
    @commands.has_role("‍♂️ FUORI SERVIZIO")
    async def entrata(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            
            orario_it = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome'))
            orario = orario_it.strftime('%H:%M')


            SimpleView.start_time = time.time()

            channel = bot.get_channel(1214495527924928522)           
            embed=discord.Embed(color=0x23a559)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://shft.cl/img/c/cdn.discordapp.com-101395680655364460.webp")
            embed.add_field(name="⬆️⬆️", value="", inline=False)                                 #BOTTONE ENTRATA
            embed.add_field(name="NOME:", value=f"{interaction.user.mention}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="DATA:", value=f"{data}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="ORARIO:", value=f"{orario}", inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="ARMERIA200")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"***SEI ENTRATO IN SERVIZIO ALLE: {orario}.***", ephemeral=True)


    @discord.ui.button(label="⬇️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="2")
    @commands.has_role("‍♂️ IN SERVIZIO")
    async def uscita(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            
            orario_it = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome'))
            orario = orario_it.strftime('%H:%M')

            
            SimpleView.stop_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = SimpleView.stop_time - SimpleView.start_time
            time_d = timedelta(seconds=int(elapsed_time))

            channel = bot.get_channel(1215061241270374400)           
            embed=discord.Embed(color=0xda373c)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://shft.cl/img/c/cdn.discordapp.com-101395680655364460.webp")
            embed.add_field(name="⬇️⬇️", value="", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="NOME:", value=f"{interaction.user.mention}", inline=True)                                        #BOTTONE USCITA
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="DATA:", value=f"{data}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="ORARIO:", value=f"{orario}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="TEMPO IN SERVIZIO:", value=f"{time_d}", inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="ARMERIA200")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"***SEI USCITO DI SERVIZIO ALLE: {orario}, DOPO: {time_d}***", ephemeral=True)
```

I want these two buttons to be able to be pressed only by those who have the "‍♂️ IN SERVIZIO" and "‍♂️ FUORI SERVIZIO" roles, I can't figure out how to do that.
I tried looking for different solutions but I can't find anything useful.
Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You‘re currently using a decorator that is ONLY designed for the commands extension of discord.py, remove it.

For making the button only available for a certain role:

Get the ID of the role you want to check for via Discords Developer settings.

Then check if the user has the roles and run the rest of the code only when he does, otherwise defer the interaction.

```py
role = interaction.guild.get_role({id here})
if role in interaction.user.roles:
   # code here
else:
   await interaction.response.defer()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, from this error:

https://imgur.com/a/b8Vzw2W

Comment: Remove the curly brackets from your id, in my example they're to show that it is a placeholder